# Uploading some.doc file to server in Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am new to Phonegap and trying to upload a .doc file to a php server running on Xampp.
For this I can use Phonegap's File-Transfer API, like I did in uploading image file to server and it works perfectly!!

For uploading any file (.doc in my case) i can use below piece of code.

```
function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
        var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.fileKey="file";
        options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

        var params = new Object();
        params.value1 = name;      //name of the user
        options.params = params;
        options.chunkedMode = false;

        var ft = new FileTransfer();
        ft.upload(imageURI, "http://localhost/upload.php", win, fail, options);
    }
```

But to use the above uploadPhoto(imageURI) method, I need to pass the fileURI.
My problem starts here, I don't know how to obtain fileURI.
If anyone can help me out with obtaining fileURI, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a plugin to choose the file, like the file chooser plugin

https://github.com/cdibened/filechooser

It will give you the url of the file and then you can use file transfer to upload.

BTW, don't use localhost on the url, that will work on the simulator, but not on a device, use the local IP of the server

Comment: Thanks for the help, That's exactly what I was looking for, but I guess this plugin will not work on IOS ?

Comment: No, is for android only. On iOS 8 might be possible to create a plugin like that, but as far as I know, it doesn't exist yet. For iOS 7 and earlier it isn't possible to get files  from outside the app